# An inequality of $L_p$ norm

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(X, m), (Y, \mu)$ are two measure spaces. Consider $f:X \times Y \to \mathbb R$ where $X  \times Y$ has product measure $m\times \mu$. Suppose $0<p\leq q$. I want to show $\|\|f\|_{L_p(m)}\|_{L_q(\mu)}\leq\|\|f\|_{L_q(\mu)}\|_{L_p(m)}$. I'm trying to write $f=f\cdot 1$ and use Cauchy Schwarz but I don't know what to do next. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Minkowski's integral inequality,
$$
\left(\int_Y\left(\int_X|f(x,y)|^p m(dx)\right)^{q/p}\mu(dy)\right)^{p/q}\le \int_X\left(\int_Y|f(x,y)|^{q} \mu(dx)\right)^{p/q}m(dx)
$$